# Square board in Java - why is result different?

Tags: java

The first piece of code results in only one column and bunch of rows. The second piece of code results in 5x5 board. What is wrong with the first piece of code. It's probably something stupid and simple, but I couldn't find it.

```
int size = 5;    // size of the board
      for (int row = 1; row <= size; ++row) {  
         for (int col = 1; col <= size; ++col) {
             System.out.println("# ");
         }
          System.out.println();
      }




int height = 5;
        int width = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                System.out.print("# ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: Because you're using `println` in the first and `print` in the second.

Comment: The first uses `println` instead of `print`

Comment: The first uses println and the second uses print ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
int size = 5;
for(int row=1;row<=size;++row)
{
    for (int col = 1; col <= size; ++col)
    {
        System.out.print("# ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

int height = 5;
int width  = 5;

for(int i=0;i<height;i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        System.out.print("# ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: This formatting gives me a headache. Please fix it. Also, explain why this answer is correct and what was wrong with OPs code, so we all can learn from it.

Comment: just change println to print because println gives all output in different line but in print this not happen